# OpenCV, cvCvtColor : null array pointer is passed in function cvgetmat

Tags: c, opencv

I'm beginning with openCV, I have to use it for a project at school. I'm using CodeBlocks on windows.

I am trying to write a very simple function that convert a image in RGB format to an HSV format, then display the Hue channel.

```
long traiter_image(IplImage* Image)
{
    IplImage* ImHSV = 0;
    IplImage* chans[3];
    cvCvtColor(Image, ImHSV, CV_BGR2HSV); // BGR to HSV

    // split channels
    cvSplit (ImHSV, chans[0], chans[1], chans[2], NULL);
    Afficher("Teinte",chans[0]); // Display Hue

    return 0;
}
```

I don't have any building errors, but when I execute the code, a windows appears, telling me that "null array pointer is passed in function cvgetmat". The problem comes from the cvCvtColor function, but I don't know how to fix it...

Comment: I suspect that you should be doing something with `ImHSV` beyond initializing it to 0 before passing it to cvCvtColor. In most (if not all) c compilers, `NULL` is zero, it sounds like the source of your error.

Comment: as this is a new project, I would suggest not using the C api (IPLImage etc) as you are going to run into significant problems if using a newer version of OpenCV.

Comment: please do **not** use opencv's deprecated c-api.

Answer (score 1):

Before calling [`cvCvtColor()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor), you should create the memory for the output image, which should be of the same size and depth as the input image.

For your case, it should be:

```
IplImage* ImHSV = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(Image), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
cvCvtColor(Image, ImHSV, CV_BGR2HSV); // BGR to HSV
```